# Is there any performance difference between view and stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I had large amount of data . I had write SQL Queries for all of these and retrieve data.My point is should i write these queries in views or SP's.
i.e i need to know is there is any major difference between

```
INSERT INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME EXEC SP
OR
INSERT INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM VIEW
```

Comment: What's the performance difference between a screwdriver and a hammer? They're completely different tools and whilst you *can* abuse one and try to use it in the other's role, you really shouldn't.

Comment: Stored procedure and views are used for different purposes, We can only compare two things they are used for same purpose, else comparison is use less

Answer (score 0):

Is there any major *performance* difference?  No, but only if the query inside the stored proc is the exact same query inside the view.  You should not see any major performance difference.  If there is a performance difference, you won't notice it.  If you start adding extra code to the proc (parameters, logic, etc.), then all bets are off.

Comment: Could you provide any sources?

Answer (score 0):

Its the matter of art, or the ability to reuse (maintenance). 
I personally, prefer using drop and create tables other than creating a complex view. Reason is simple, any one will have to understand the logic from one single screen other than opening multi tables, views, GUI code, and maybe Reports processes.

Answer (score 0):

If the query inside the stored procedure is exactly the same as the query in the view. The query analizer should use the same execution plan.

I have ran some tests here, with the same query in a SP and a view. Both have similar execution times at around 6 seconds for each type with the SP being a bit slower. But this was just a test with a simple sql statement.